# how to compare dates(yyyy-mm-dd) stored in database and sort them in android

Tags: android

I am storing 3 different dates as start date, end date, alarm date.

I have converted them to strings and stored them in a sqlite database, now I want to compare those 3 dates with each other such that the dates should be entered into database only if it follows the condition otherwise it has to show an alert box to enter an proper date.

The conditions are

1. Alarm date should be less-than (or) equal to start date and not greater than end date
2. Start date should be less than (or) equal to end date and not greater than end date
3. End date should be greater than (or) equal to start date but not less than alarm date

The dates should be entered into database only if they satisfy the above conditions.
Can anyone help me with this, with some sample code?

Comment: are using time also yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss means hour min and sec or not for accuracy

Comment: What have you tried? show your code. [anyways nice documented Requirement to pass it to developer to be done]

Answer (score 0):

you may pick up the date from database as string, then convert it as Calendar, use calendar's `equal(), before(), after()` methods. I think this is the best way.

---

UPDATED:

For format like YYYY-MM-DD

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(startDate);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken("-"));
        int month = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken("-"));
        int date= Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken("-"));
        Calendar calStartDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        calStartDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date);
        calStartDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
        calStartDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
```

Same as convert other dates like endDate/alarmDate

now apply `calStartDate.before(calAlarmDate)` etc. as per your condition.

Comment: I mean you may check the above listed conditions using equal(), before(), after() methods as Calendar object.